# IOS 8.1 Safari:$.ajax giving timeout error dom exception 23

Tags: jquery, ajax, ios8.1

I am using a **iPhone 5S**, with **iOS version 8.1**. When I debug my web application having some jquery ajax calls, I am consistently getting my `error` callback method executed. I also tried to specify timeout to a high value (like 20,000 ms) like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: serviceURL,
    data: userInputjson,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    async: false,
    timeout: 20000,
    complete: function (msg) {

        if(msg.responseJSON) {
            msg = msg.responseJSON;
            alert('msg.responseJSON exists');
            console.log(msg);

            if (msg.Status == 'SUCCESS') {
                var obj = JSON.parse(userInputjson);
                var firstName,lastName,email;
                for(i=0; i< obj.fields.length; i++){  
                    if(obj.fields[i].Key =="FirstName")
                    { 
                        firstName = obj.fields[i].Value;

                    }else if(obj.fields[i].Key =="LastName"){
                        lastName = obj.fields[i].Value;

                    }else if(obj.fields[i].Key =="Email"){
                        email = obj.fields[i].Value;

                    }
                }
                alert("before cookie");
                $.cookie(DHLoginCookieName, {
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName,
                    emial:email,
                    isLoggedIn: true
                });
                alert("after cookie");
                window.top.location.href = "thankyou.html";
            }
            else
            {
                alert("in else");
                $(".regLoader").hide();
                $("#submiterror").show();
            }

            return false;
        }
    },
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert("Error status 2: "+textStatus+"\n"+errorThrown);
        if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 0 || xmlHttpRequest.status == 0) {
            $(".regLoader").hide();
            $("#submiterror").show();
            return ;
        }
    }
})
```

with no effect, whatsoever.

Anybody please tell me what could be wrong on my end.

Comment: Without seeing the AJAX request code, any errors you receive and possibly the server side code, no one is going to be able to help you from the little information you've posted

Comment: I understand. Actually, webservice code is a bit humongous.

Comment: BTW you can't set a timeout on an "async:false: call. The code in jQuery $.ajax prevents it - I think it's a standard of some sort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change **async: false** to **async: true** , it may help